# USB automount fail "Not Authorized"

Tags: linux, usb, nautilus, automount

USB automount worked well for several month but after some updates Nautilus displays [image].

With these commands it works well :

```
aubin@Breizh-Atao:~$ sudo fdisk -l

[...]

Disk /dev/sdf: 15.6 GB, 15610576896 bytes
119 heads, 55 sectors/track, 4658 cylinders, total 30489408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1   *        8064    30489407    15240672    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
aubin@Breizh-Atao:~$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdf1 /media/usb/
aubin@Breizh-Atao:~$
```

**How can I recover the correct settings, available with automount?**

*Note:* `uname -a` returns

```
Linux Breizh-Atao 4.6.0-040600-generic #201606100558 SMP Fri Jun 10 10:01:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems an authorization issue. Of course, root have permission to mount but others users aren't allowed by polkit to automount. ( later lasts updates )

For Debian or derivatives, create:

```
 sudo vim /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/55-storage.pkla
```

with:

```
[Storage Permissions]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach;org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock;org.freedesktop.udisks.inhibit-polling;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-set-spindown
ResultAny=yes
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=no
```

Add your user to plugdev group: ( Usually added by default)

```
 sudo usermod -a -G plugdev <your username>
```

and reboot.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66654/how-to-mount-usb-stick-on-debian-sid

Comment: No, your proposal has no effect, the message is still displayed.